# Getting variable from url when it is defined with a # and not a?

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and would like to build a web app for my school.

I have got the oauth down, and my redirect URl is

`127.0.0.1/authorize`

This results in, when succesfulyl authenticated, `127.0.0.1/authorize/#access_token=thenmycodehere`

Now, being new to PHP, I cannot figure out how to get the access_token variable.

If the `#` was a `?`, then I could do it.

Is it possible?

`exec("python getlinks.py " . $_GET["access_token"]);`

Comment: I would suggest fixing the authorize script so it does not put a `#` in the url

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, I don't have access to the script, I am using Pushbullets OAuth

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Browser won't even send a request with a hash part.

Only way is just send this `access_token` using some clientside js code.

To somebody saying it's possible - I want to prove that it's not!

Here is the prove:

1) create `hash.php` file and put this contents:

```
<?php

echo "SERVER<br/>";
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "<hr/>";
echo "REQUEST<br/>";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

2) go to link and check: http://num8er.me/hash.php#access_token=blablabla

Comment: Is it possible to perhaps, get the url, then removes everythings before the access token? The access token is the very last thing in the url, and always has an = before it

Comment: Dear @WillB just have some clientside code that will get it from window.location.hash and send to backend using ajax.